# Convert JSON FILE to XML FILE using POWERSHELL

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I need to convert Json file from web to xml file and i need very simple way... There are several data I need from Json response...
There are a lot of around but they are not very clear.
I found some samples like this:

```
PS c:\0> ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject temp_JSON.json -As String   

PS c:\0> ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject temp_JSON.json -As document
```

but I can't see or find result... Where I'm wrong.

this is Json response string to convert :

```
"{"data":[{"id":"86xEyb****lUsw==","custom_fields":{"firstName":"Z***n","lastName":"Pe***ki","locale":"EN-GB_MK","timezone":"8","gender":"N\/A","phone":"+38***6","email":null},"tags":[],"created_at":1600276472}],"links":{"first":"http:\/\/app.respond.io\/api\/v1\/contact\/by_custom_field?name=firstName&value=zoran&page=1","last":"http:\/\/app.respond.io\/api\/v1\/contact\/by_custom_field?name=firstName&value=zoran&page=1","prev":null,"next":null},"meta":{"current_page":1,"from":1,"last_page":1,"path":"http:\/\/app.respond.io\/api\/v1\/contact\/by_custom_field","per_page":10,"to":1,"total":1}}"
```

@Guenther Schmitz answer works perfect,
But I need some more to ask about style of xml. I receive output like

```
<Objects>
   <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
      <Property Name="data" Type="System.Object[]">
         <Property Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
            <Property Name="id" Type="System.String">*******</Property>
         <Property Name="custom_fields"  Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
             <Property Name="firstName" Type="System.String">B***</Property>
             <Property Name="lastName" Type="System.String">B***</Property> ...
```

But I tried conversion at Json to xml web converters and I got another xml format, which is more convenient to me, I need to import data to database and I need simple xml format, so I need that way like  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <data>
    <id>nh****93UhUrQ==</id>
    <custom_fields>
      <firstName>BI**NA</firstName>
      <lastName>B**AK</lastName>
      <locale>EN_MK</locale> ...
```

Is it possible to get another xml output style.

In mean time time I founded that if you add this parameter :

```
-notypeinformation
```

```
it will clear up types from xml, so the line would be:
$XML = ConvertTo-Xml -As Stream -InputObject $JsonObject -Depth 3 -notypeinformation
```

But still remain: <Property Name="firstName" ... instead name

Answer (score 2):

you first have to convert the json-file to a PowerShell Object like

```
$JsonObject = Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\temp_JSON.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

this can then be used for the parameter `InputObject`

```
$XML = ConvertTo-Xml -As Stream -InputObject $JsonObject -Depth 3
```

*Note the parameter `Depth`. You might have to play around with this one depending on your structure as the default value is 1. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml?view=powershell-7) for reference.*

the resulting XML Object can then be saved to a file using the command `Out-File`

```
Out-File -FilePath "C:\path\to\temp_XML.xml" -InputObject $XML
```

this can also be done in one line through piping.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\temp_JSON.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Xml -As Stream -Depth 3 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\path\to\temp_XML.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks @Guenther Schmitz, that is step forward, I need that way. I tried line in PS Console but unfortunately it was empty file xml created, no data inside

Comment: only this inside                                                                                                               xml                          Objects
---                            -------
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Objects

Comment: PS C:\> Get-Content -Path "C:\0\temp_JSON.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Xml -As Document -Depth 3 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\0\temp_XML.xml"     I use this,am i i wrong somewhere

Comment: what is the content of the json? can you add that to your question?

Comment: I added json string in main question, if I open json file from browser is shown correctly

Comment: I try to examine to power shell console and it seems to that the second line $xml = converto-xml... create empty object

Comment: I updated my answer and changed the parameter `-As` from `Document` to `Stream`. sorry!

Comment: Thanks @Guenther Schmitz, It works now, I tested, It will be better if you add encoding to list line `Out-File -FilePath "C:\0\temp_XML.xml" -Encoding utf8`

Comment: I add some notes to main question, could you check them please

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to have specific nodes instead of Property nodes you should the following custom function
**Convert-CustomObjectToXml**

This snippet was originally done by [Eric Wannemacher Blog](https://blog.wannemacher.us/posts/p430/)
and then improved by [Nathan Kulas](https://github.com/omrsafetyo)

```
Function Convert-CustomObjectToXml {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [PSCustomObject]$object,
        [Int32]$depth = 1,
        [String]$rootEl = "root",
        [String]$indentString = "  ",
        [Int32]$indent = 1,
        [switch]$isRoot = $true,
        [String]$XmlVersion = "1.0",
        [String]$Encoding = "UTF-8"
    )
    BEGIN {
        $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    }
    
    PROCESS {
        # Output the root element opening tag
        if ($isRoot) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("<{0}>" -f $rootEl))
        }
        
        ForEach ( $item in $object ) {
            # Iterate through all of the note properties in the object.
            foreach ($prop in (Get-Member -InputObject $item -MemberType NoteProperty)) {
                $children = $item.($prop.Name)
                foreach ($child in $children) {
                    # Check if the property is an object and we want to dig into it
                    if ($child.GetType().Name -eq "PSCustomObject" -and $depth -gt 1) {
                        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}<{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name))
                        Convert-CustomObjectToXml $child -isRoot:$false -indent ($indent + 1) -depth ($depth - 1) -indentString $indentString | ForEach-Object { [void]$sb.AppendLine($_) }
                        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}</{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name))
                    }
                    else {
                        # output the element or elements in the case of an array
                        foreach ($element in $child) {
                            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}<{1}>{2}</{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name, $element))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     
        # If this is the root, close the root element and convert it to Xml and output
        if ($isRoot) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("</{0}>" -f $rootEl))
            [xml]$Output = $sb.ToString()
            $xmlDeclaration = $Output.CreateXmlDeclaration($XmlVersion,$Encoding,$null)
            [void]$Output.InsertBefore($xmlDeclaration, $Output.DocumentElement)
            $Output
        }
        else {
            # If this is the not the root, this has been called recursively, output the string
            Write-Output $sb.ToString()
        }
    }
    END {}
}
```